# Get pixel's color in C++, Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I'm looking for a possibility to get the color of a pixel with given screen coordinates (x,y) in c++ / Linux? Maybe something similarly like getPixel() in Windows. I spent the whole day to find sth but without any success.

Thanks, Stefan

Comment: You really want to do that... Ouch... you're entering a world of pain, man...

Comment: that, or any other solution to get the color of a pixel in a firefox extension. right now i'm trying to find a solution with a xpcom c++ compononent...

Comment: Do you want do to this in X or a virtual terminal? I second mingos - pain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See various different techniques posted at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=715256

Comment: thanks, i already found this topic. actually there's no c++ solution and i'm thinking now about dismissing my firefox-extension (for the xpcom component i have to write in c++) and just create a java-application instead.

Comment: @Stefan, you can port the Python Xlib example into C/C++.

Comment: didn't really work for me but it gave me the right direction. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean using C and GTK the answer can be using:

```
gdk_get_default_root_window()
```

And

```
GdkPixbuf*  gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable    (GdkPixbuf *dest,
                                             GdkDrawable *src,
                                             GdkColormap *cmap,
                                             int src_x,
                                             int src_y,
                                             int dest_x,
                                             int dest_y,
                                             int width,
                                             int height);
```

EDIT: sample c++ code using Gdkmm (note that this is just a sample that assume an RGB color space, you should check the colorspace of the drawable before giving a meaning to the raw bytes).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <gdkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
  if(argc != 3) { std::cerr << argv[0] << " x y" << std::endl; return 1;}
  int x = atoi(argv[1]);
  int y = atoi(argv[2]);
  Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Screen> screen = Gdk::Screen::get_default();
  Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Drawable> win = screen->get_root_window();
  Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> pb = Gdk::Pixbuf::create(win, x, y, 1, 1);
  unsigned char* rgb = pb->get_pixels();
  std::cerr << (int)rgb[0] << ", " << (int)rgb[1] << ", " << (int)rgb[2] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you run `gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable` on the root window, will it tell you the pixel color in the root window (even if it's obscured by another window), or it tell you the color of whatever window is on top above that pixel?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this same issue and have found the solution to be dependant on the situation at hand. A great way to go about doing it is to capture a bitmap of the window you are looking at. Then have a function search for the pixel in there that you are looking for. Keep in mind the x,y coords will start from the windows upper left corner as apposed to the screen's upper left. As to how to do this, I suggest you take a look at SCAR Divi witten by Freddy1990 http://freddy1990.com/ and Simba http://villavu.com/.

Those programs are used to program automated tasks on the computer and use pixel colour finding to achieve some tasks. Simba is open source and still in its infant stages. It uses pascal. However you could use the library it uses as an extention from C and sacrifice a little speed.